# "std::" data-structure with sorting/ordering, existance tests, and head/tail access?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I need a data structure (std preferred) that boasts:

- sorting (upon insertion if possible)
- comparison (by random-access, or member function) to determine if an object already exists in the structure
- ability to retrieve, and remove lead/trailing element

I considered vector, but no real support for sorting exists, but did have the other 2

I also considered priority-queue, but need to have the ability to compare against what is already there.

Comment: Can use a binary-search with a PQ?

Comment: @pst could you please elaborate, or direct to documentation on your suggestion.

Comment: Did you tried STL Map. `Internally, the elements in the map are sorted from lower to higher key value following a specific strict weak ordering criterion set on construction.` Also `find` (Get iterator to desired element), `count` (Count elements with a specific key) methods are available. Check this, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/

Comment: I don't use C++; just throwing it out there if the PQ supported indexing :)

Comment: @Rupak, two things: 1) STL is much wider term than "c++ standard library" and generally covers _another_ library than c++stdlib. Use "stdlib" instead. 2) Don't ever link to cplusplus.com, use cppreference.com instead - the site you linked is known as one of worst possible source of documentation on C++.

Comment: @Griwes, thank you. I thought the `std` in question was for the namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::set`.

1. It sorts the elements inserted into it.
2. To check whether an element already exists you can use `set::find`.
3. To retrieve the leading element you can use `set::begin` iterator and to last element you can use `set::rbegin`. To remove these elements you can use `set::erase` method.

Comment: does this allow for sorting based on different means then comparison. have an element inserted, and sorted by a member var(done through a operator method), and then checked against with the classes operator==()

Comment: You can provide your own comaprison function which can control the sorting order. But note that you can not *resort* a set on different attribute.

Comment: I ment more for find does that just do a full compare of the objects, or will it attempt to use the operator== as some of the members might be different, but the operator== does not take them into consideration

Comment: set uses what is called *strict weak ordering*. It uses whether two obejcts are *equivalent* (note it does not check whether they are *equal*) using the `operator<` provided by you.  Take a look at `set` documentation here: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a list?  It seems to fit your request, you would have to sort after each insertion or after you have the list complete, but it does have a sort function as part of the template.  It has functions to access the front and back elements as well as forward and reverse iterators. Here is the reference I found on line which may be helpful:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list.  I'm sure there are other examples as well.